# Add a column full of NAs in Sparkr

Tags: r, sparkr

How do I add a column full of `NA` in a `SparkR` `DataFrame` ? This doesn't work.

```
> df <- data.frame(cola = 1:4)
> sprkrDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
> sprkrDF$colb <- NA
Error: class(value) == "Column" || is.null(value) is not TRUE
```

Thanks

---

NB : I want to add it directly to the `SparkR` `DataFrame`, so this is not the solution I'm looking for :

```
> df <- data.frame(cola = 1:4, colb = NA)
> sprkrDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `lit()` to create a new column and fill it with `NA`'s.

```
sprkrDF <- withColumn(sprkrDF, "colb", lit(NULL))
```

Comment: I get `16/06/14 15:11:15 WARN RBackendHandler: cannot find matching method class org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit. Candidates are:
16/06/14 15:11:15 WARN RBackendHandler: lit(class java.lang.Object)
16/06/14 15:11:15 ERROR RBackendHandler: lit on org.apache.spark.sql.functions failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :`

Comment: Yeah, I ended figuring that `NA` doesn't exist in `SparkR` `DataFrame`s and `NULL` must be used... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that @mtoto 's answer is the right answer for the specific question you asked.  An alternative approach is to populate the NA values in the R data.frame before you create the Spark DataFrame.  Working in base R can make some tasks easier when (a) you don't need distributed processing power and (b) you want to index specific rows in the data.

```
df <- data.frame(cola = 1:4)
df$colb <- NA
sprkrDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
```

Glad to see that someone else has learned to prefix R and Spark dataframe names clearly! ... I always use rdf for "R data.frame" and sdf for "Spark DataFrame" to make my code more readable :-)