# Append a column of NA values: lit() and withColumn() giving error

Tags: r, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to append a column of null values to a SparkR DataFrame with the following code:

```
w <- rbind(3, 0, 2, 3, NA, 1)
z <- rbind("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
x <- rbind(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

d <- cbind.data.frame(w, z, x)
B <- as.DataFrame(sqlContext, d)

B1 <- sample(B, withReplacement = FALSE, fraction = 0.5)
B2 <- except(B, B1)

col_sub <- c("z", "x")
B2 <- select(B2, col_sub)

B2 <- withColumn(B2, "w", lit(NA))
```

But, the last expression returns the error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unsupported data type:  null`. I have used the `lit` operation to produce a column of null values before, but I'm not sure why it won't work this time.

Also, this has been discussed on SE before, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812295/add-a-column-full-of-nas-in-sparkr). I'm completely clueless as to why my expression yields that error. For reference, I'm using SparkR 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if it works or not adding column this way is not a good practice. Since the only practical reason to add column which contains only undefined values is  enforcing specific schema for unions or external writes you should always use columns of specific type.

For example:

```
withColumn(B2, "w", cast(lit(NULL), "double"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark columns can have types numeric, character.  My understanding is that it is intended that columns of other data types are illegal.

NA is not recognized by SparkR in the same way that R recognizes it as being an indicator of a missing value.  SparkR sees NA as being a value of type logical.  For example:

```
dtypes(NA)
```

`unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dtypes’ for signature ‘"logical"’`

If you try to add a column of NA's, Spark tries to create a column of type logical, which is not a valid data type for a column.  Hence the error.

There are a couple of places where SparkR (1.6.2) is inconsistent in trapping errors around creating illegal column types.  As you found, SparkR throws an error if you use `lit(NA)`, but SparkR will let you convert an R data.frame with a column of NAs and it successfully creates an illegal column of type "logical"

```
x <- c(NA,NA,NA, NA, NA)
dfX <- data.frame(x)
colnames(dfX) <- c("Empty")
sdfX <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, dfX)
str(sdfX)

'DataFrame': 1 variables:
 $ Empty: logi NA NA NA NA NA
```